# NewRelic tracking background transaction and in node.js after http response is send

Tags: javascript, node.js, newrelic

I implemented a simple tracker in node.js. Directly on socket connection I respond with a transparent gif. This results in a web transaction response time of 1-2 sec. After this I process the data, validate, store it in the database and so on.

I'd like to analyze with new relic how long the actual processing takes, how many async db queries run in parallel and if any errors occur during processing. Is it possible to track this with new relic?

Answer (score 1):

I work for New Relic, yes it is possible to monitor this application with our Node agent.
Give it a go and let us know if you need any help.

Comment: The overhead is normally negligible.

Comment: I would expect it to pick up your applications transactions, if not you can manually add them: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/nodejs-custom-instrumentation#background-txn